# Put model's id in hidden input in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to put a hidden input in my template containing my model's id. This is what I have:

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']

        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(),
        }
```

index.html:

```
{{ form.name.label_tag }}
{{ form.name }}
```

This works fine and displays a simple form with a text input. What I want to do is add a hidden input that contains the model's id. I tried:

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'id']

        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(),
            'id': HiddenInput(),
        }
```

index.html:

```
{{ form.name.label_tag }}
{{ form.name }}
{{ form.id }}
```

But it doesn't work. If possible I wanted to avoid manually doing this:

index.html:

```
{{ form.name.label_tag }}
{{ form.name }}
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ form.instance.id }}">
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

My overall goal is to have a form that edits an existing model. So I retrieve a model using the ORM and display it on the form. When I submit the form to update the object, I need to know its id in order for the ORM to know which object to update. Thanks!

Comment: manual version is OK.

Comment: Do you not want to set the `id` value in your view either?

Comment: Try `{{ form.id.as_hidden }}`.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov it didn't work

Comment: @jape I'd rather handle this in either the models or the forms, if possible

Comment: @furas I guess it is

Comment: What's your overall goal? I understand you want it as a hidden input, but what are you planning on doing with the input? That'll give us a better understanding of how to help you

Comment: I added the overall goal in the question. Thanks for taking the time to help out!